# WSDualHttpBinding wont work on some computers

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex, wsdualhttpbinding

I have an wcf that uses an wsdusalhttpbinding

```
WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, baseAddress + "/ws");

//Mex
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

_host.Open();
```

Now this works on my computer and one of my colleagues but on some computers we get this error.

[image]

The stacktrace leads to this line.

```
_host.Open();
```

I dont understand why it would say WebHttpBinding the only endpoint I use for this service is the one I create with the code I wrote.

Comment: hmm i disabled the whole windows Firewall and uninstalled all virus software i could find on one of the faulting computers. i did not work any better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i found the problem!

.net 4.0 on the faulted computers had the os "Windows embedded" or POS ready OS.
there must be something missing in the OS of those computers because i installed .NET 4.5 even though my project only requires 4.0. and now it works.

I have no idea what the error message means but its maybe som wrong pointer or something.